# Evaluating $\sum_{r=1}^{89} \frac{1}{1+\tan^3 r}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

> $$\sum_{r=1}^{89} \frac{1}{1+\tan^3 r }$$
> where $r$ is in degrees

I tried this a lot using the $a^3+b^3$ identity but I don't seem to be getting anything fruitful :(

Can someone please give me a hint? I don't think the $V_n$ method is working here. ($T_r+T_{r-1}$)

Is it related to the $\tan(A+B)$ identity? However I'm not getting anything through that too.

I would be grateful if someone helped. Thanks!

Comment: You could try to work out something with  $$1+\tan^3r=\frac{\cos^3r+\sin^3r}{\cos^3r}=\frac{\cos^2r-\cos r\sin r+\sin^2r}{\cos^3r}=\frac{1-\cos r\sin r}{\cos^3r}$$

Comment: @DonAntonio The second equality is false.

Comment: @jjagmath Yep: $$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$ and the factor $\;(\cos r+\sin r)\;$ is missing. May the OP fulfill this. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $S=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{89} \cfrac{1}{1+\tan^3 r }$

$S=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{89} \cfrac{\cos^3r}{\cos^3r+\sin^3 r }$

Now Since  $\displaystyle\sum_{r=a}^{b}f(r)=\displaystyle\sum_{r=a}^{b}f(a+b-r)$

Using which we get $S=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{89} \cfrac{\cos^3(90-r)}{\cos^3(90-r)+\sin^3(90-r) }=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{89} \cfrac{\sin^3r}{\cos^3r+\sin^3 r }$

Therefore $S=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{89} \frac{\cos^3r}{\cos^3r+\sin^3 r} =\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{89} \frac{\sin^3r}{\cos^3r+\sin^3 r }$

Therefore $2S=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{89} \cfrac{\sin^3r+\cos^3r}{\cos^3r+\sin^3 r }=\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{89} 1=89$

Therefore $S=\displaystyle \boxed{{\frac{89}{2}}}$